# Angular 4 how to sum field in model

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I sum fields N1 to N5 in model Trans?

```
public class Trans
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int N1 { get; set; }
    public int N2 { get; set; }
    public int N3 { get; set; }
    public int N4 { get; set; }
    public int N5 { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
trans: Trans = new Trans();
trans.N1 = 1;
trans.N2 = 2;
trans.N3 = 3;
trans.N4 = 4;
trans.N5 = 5;
```

...

Then I would to sum trans.N1 + trans.N2 + ... + trans.N5

Is it possible way to do that?

Comment: I also can do the max() function.

getMax(o) {
        let max = 0;
        return Object.keys( o).reduce( ( max, key )=> (max<o[key])? o[key]: max, 0);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
let sum = Object.keys( trans).reduce( ( sum, key )=>sum + trans[key] , 0);
```

this will also include the id, if you want to ignore it you should do by if(key !== 'id')

if you want every Trans object to have that option just add inside the class
(**Please note : this should work but I havn't tested it**) :

```
get sum(): number {
  return Object.keys( this).reduce( ( sum, key )=>sum + this[key], 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an helper function in your class that sums up all of the elements

```
public class Trans
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int N1 { get; set; }
    public int N2 { get; set; }
    public int N3 { get; set; }
    public int N4 { get; set; }
    public int N5 { get; set; }

    public sumAllMemebers(){
      return this.N1 + this.N2 + this.N3 + this.N4 + this.N5;
    }
}
```

and then you can just call it like this, `trans.sumAllMemebers()` and it will return the sum.